# Remove frame and icons from jupyteLab cell after one click

Tags: interface, jupyter-lab

after several months without calculations I need to go back to JupyterLab. The interface has changed a bit and I wish it didn't. If I click on a cell now there appear a frame with a set of icons on the right. Is it possible to avoid this? In the image you see in red the elements I would prefer not to see, as it was before. Before it was more mode-oriented, like vi, and I preferred it.
[image]

Comment: Documentation can answer your question about disabling the cell toolbar: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/notebook.html#cell-toolbar. As for the frame around markdown cells - please do open an issue on https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues